# Set property to "not defined here" in CSS?

Tags: css

Is it possible to set properties in CSS to "not defined here"?

Imagine this example.

```
<div class="intro-text">
    This text should be big and have padding on all sides.
</div>
<div class="intro-text no-tb-padding">
    This text should also be big, but only have padding left & right.
</div>

.intro-text {
    font-size: large;
    padding: 1em 2em;
}
.no-tb-padding {
    padding: [what here?];
    ...
```

Now, here's the thing. I'd like to set `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to 0 for the later class. I know this can be done with just those two rules. But is there a way in CSS to define it like this?

```
padding: 0 [defined somewhere else];
```

With this the former class would define the left & right padding, but the later would define the top & bottom one.

Is this currently possible in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of a shorthand property is to allow you to specify *all* applicable values in a single declaration. Since you're trying *not* to set certain property values, you should not be using — and indeed you cannot use — a shorthand property. You'll have to set the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` properties separately.

Comment: ...and css preprocessors like Less/sass support variables that let you do as you intend.

Answer (score 3):

For a workflow like that, you'd love SASS or LESS.

For this specific example, just set padding-right and padding-left:

```
padding-right: 0;
padding-left: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I use LESS, that is a CSS framework, and it is very usefull.
ex. You can use a variable and give it to as many classes as you want, and then, all have the same description, that is defined in only one place.
To use in normal CSS, you can just add:

```
padding-right: 0;
padding-left: 0;
```

Because the padding top and bottom will be taken by the previous class.
Hope it help.